# when running SSMS "as Administrator" whose rights are used for physical file permissions when creating a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've opened SSMS "as Administrator", and would like to create a database, storing the files in a particular folder on the D: drive.  The operation is failing with this error:

> "CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5 (Access is denied)
>   while attempting to open or create the physical file `D:\DATA\FOO.MDF`
>   "

Which entity needs permissions to that folder?

Answer (score 4):

The SQL Server service account is ostensibly the account which will be creating the file. It isn't your account. But the service account. That said, sometimes I've seen issue where UAC can cause issues and you need to run as Administrator.

If you use the SQL Server Configuration manager to change service account the necessary permissions should be granted but it could be you are trying to write to a drive not originally configured or that has bad permissions changed. Should be the service account, though. SQL Server service, not agent.